# Cannot turn on atrun to use "at" commands

Tags: macos, at

In Mac OS 10.15.5, I can run the command:

```
echo "mkdir foldername" | at now + 1 minute
```

and it "runs" (i.e. it doesn't give me any error), and when I run `atq`, it lists it in the queue. The problem is that these things in the queue never actually get executed. People say that I have to enable atrun; when I try to run:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

It says I don't have permission, and this is where I am stuck. I even tried opening the plist with xcode, but it won't let me save the changes.